# how to update google chart?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

Am new to angularjs/googlecharts and learning on the job. I've the following code in my controller which renders the piechart initially and has no issues.

There is a slider directive, which when changed (basically a date range slider), should update the columnchart with new data. But I don't know how to update the piechart data. I do get the new data from the backend without any problems though.

Here is the initialization code in controller:

```
                $scope.piechart = {};
                $scope.piechart.type ='PieChart';                   
                piechartData = response.data.piechart;
                var piechartoptions = {
                    'min-width':800,
                    'max-width':320,
                    'is3D':true,
                    'pieSliceText': 'label',
                    'pieSliceTextStyle': {fontSize: 10},
                    'chartArea' : { left: 30, top: 60 },
                    'backgroundColor': {fill:'transparent'},
                    'legend': {'textStyle':{'color': 'white',
                                            'fontSize': 12},
                               'position': "top",
                               'maxLines':10,
                               'alignment':"start"},
                    'height':500
                };

         $scope.piechart.data = new google.visualization.DataTable(piechartData);
         $scope.piechart.options = piechartoptions;
         $scope.piechart.formatters = {};
```

In the directive (which is used in the html that the above controller's scope resides in), I've access to the chart like the following:

```
scope.$parent.piechart
```

So in a very naive way i did this but to no avail:

```
scope.$parent.piechart.data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.data.piechart)
```

TIA for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you need to create watch on your slider model so when it gets change you need to update your pie chart model so it'll automatically update.

**Watch**

```
$scope.$watch('sliderModel',function(n,o) {
      // update your new pie chart data here, I think you need to update below model only
    $scope.piechart.data = new google.visualization.DataTable(piechartData);
}
```

It just an example. You have to update it with new data for pie chart.

**Proper Angular way to use google chart**

You should use google-chart directives to plot pie chart so this kind of problems will be solved automatically.

Have a look here - [Angular-google-chart](https://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/generic/PieChart)

Comment: Thanks Jay, I actually put the above statement (scope.$piechart.data =....) in a onFinish event (am using rangeslider) but still it does not work. The original chart remains as it is and no error is thrown.

Comment: wrap it inside $scope.$apply(function(){}) or it will be great if you can create js fiddle.

Comment: I tried calling scope.$parent.$apply() but got Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress..what to do.

Comment: Jay you are right. creating the scope.$parent.$apply() worked!

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this issue today. An easy quick fix is to simply write
this.chartData = Object.assign([], this.chartData) to reassign to the exposed dataset property into your component so it triggers change detection.

More information from this issue in a different library:
valor-software/ng2-charts#959 (comment)

Hope this helps weary travellers :)